# Store an image in a SQL Server CE database C# Compact framework code

Tags: c#, image, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, store

Hello I want to Insert Image to Database SQL CE using C# Compact framework..

my code

```
FileInfo Filfo=New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToSting());
Long LngLength=5;
FileStream fstrm=new FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToSting());
BinaryReader br=new BinaryReader(Fstrm);
byte[] data=br.ReadBytes(int)lngLenght);

string Query="insert into category(cm_id,cm_image) values(@id,@img)";
sqlcecommand cmd=new sqlcecommand(Query,cls.Connect());
cmd.parameters.add(new sqlcparameter("@id",(object)textbox1.text);
cmd.parameters.add(new sqlcparameter("@id",(object)data);
cmd.executenonquery();
```

but it showing error....
openfiledialog1 ,file not found....

my load image code

```
openfiledialog open=new opendailog();
open.filter="Image Files(*.jpg*bmp;|*.jpg;*bmp;

if(open.showdilog()==dialogresult.Ok)
{
    pitcherbox1.image=new bitmap(open.file);
}
```

Comment: Put breakpoint at error line and look at OpenFileDialog1.FileName value. What is it equals to?

Comment: You are using the `BinaryReader` wrong.

Comment: also you are setting the @id parameter twice (likely this is a typo on the question only)

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo Filfo=New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToSting());
Long LngLength=5;
FileStream fstrm=new FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToSting());
BinaryReader br=new BinaryReader(Fstrm);
byte[] data=br.ReadBytes(int)lngLenght);    
string Query="insert into category(cm_id,cm_image) values(@id,@img)";
sqlcecommand cmd=new sqlcecommand(Query,cls.Connect());
cmd.parameters.add(new sqlcparameter("@id",(object)textbox1.text);
cmd.parameters.add(new sqlcparameter("@img",(object)data);
cmd.executenonquery();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it looks like the filter is invalid.

Try just `*.jpg;*.bmp`